# What's the best way to persist a dynamic "info" object, C#/.Net MVC/SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

This may sound like a pipe dream, I'm wondering if it's possible. I want to be able to take a C# dynamic object, called info, and persist it to a database (I'm currently on a SQL Server 2008 database).

The info object, being dynamic, could have any number of properties: `Id, Title, Content, DateExpires, DateAdded, Dateupdated, TypeOf`, etc...

Each instance of it could/will contain differing number of properties, depending on what the instance is used for: blog post, classified ad, event, etc... However, there would be a core set of properties every info object would share: `Id, MemberId, TypeOf`...

The idea is, to have a central table which stores all dynamic info objects, yet, allow me to query based on any property (which may not exist for some objects).

For example, blog posts. They'd have: `Id, MemberId, DateAdded, Title, Content, TypeOf,` etc... An event would have: `Id, MemberId, Title, Content, TypeOf, DateOf, Recurrance, MinAge, MaxAge,` etc...

I'd like to build queries based on any given info object property.

Why? Flexibility. If I can get this working, I can use the info object for future cases within my web app. If this is an extremely bad idea, please let me know (and why) please. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Massive, its a tool written by Rob Conery, what you might be able to do is have you base table and then read the objects back into dynamic class, it's a bit backwards to the way you were planning on doing it though. But it does sound possible.

Comment: You could always have a table with the "core" properties as "normal" columns (those that exist for almost all objects) and then store the remainder of the properties into an XML structure in the SQL Server table....

Comment: @Jethro funny you mention Massive, I do currently use Massive to access the data in my app. ;) However, I'd have to create a separate field for every possible property... unless I'm missing some technique?

Comment: @narc_s thanks. As an XML structure, would it be queryable? Could I query for info objects between MinAge and MaxAge... given that those fields would be within the XML structure?

Comment: @Chad: yes - you can "peek" into the XML using XPath/XQuery, and if needed, you can "pull up" certain values from the XML into computed columns on your host table for even easier querying ....

Comment: @Chad, let me know if you find a solution for this please. Would like to take a look.

Comment: Have you considered a document database rather than a RDBMS? it might be a better fit here.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I was just reading up on RavenDB when you posted this. ;) I think you're right, a Document DB may be a better fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible and I've seen many systems built like this...however those systems are usually the hardest to maintain due to this "generic nature". There is nothing inherently wrong with this approach. It's just that it's much harder to pull it off and in most instances it ends up being a poorly implemented.

In recent years non-relational databases (like document databases that @Marc Gravell mentioned) have caught up and they are very good for some domains but you need to make sure it's the right fit for your project.

When you take the path of building this "generic database" you are sacrificing other well-known technologies that we take for granted. For example database optimization in relational databases is well-known and there are many tools that work well with them with little or no effort. If you go a different path all of a sudden the tools that you are used to might not work and will end up either building your own to make up for the stuff that does not work (or buying/choosing some esoteric tools.)

Depending on the size of your project it might be wise to build one or two of those systems that you think would be common and then try to see if they are as common as you think.

Comment: I think you're right Hector. The more deeply I get into planning/thinking of this, the more headaches I uncover. I think I'm going to scrap this idea. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a 'base' table for the common properties, and a property name-value table for the other properties. meaning:

```
Table Info
  int Id (PK) (FK),
  int MemberId,
  Date DateAdded //etc...

Table Properties
  int InfoId (PK),
  varchar PropertyName (PK),
  varchar PropertyValue,
  string PropertyType //optionaly store information about the type of property
```

after querying, you can use reflection to translate the properties from (name,value) pairs into proper properties.

That said, I think that this *is* a very bad idea, for several reasons:
1. this creates further complexity on your CRUD logic
2. you don't have well-defined entities in your domain model, which I don't like
3. validation is that much more difficult- you have to manually verify that `Post`, for example, doesn't have a property called `Recurrance` field.

I would use this method only if you truly **need** this flexibility- for example: if a user can choose to save custom properties that you don't know in advance.
otherwise, if you know that your entities are limited to `Post`, `Event`, `Employee` etc.., I would just limit myself to that.

Comment: See [10 common database design mistakes](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/) - point no. 9 and [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) point no. 3 - this anti-pattern is called Entity-Attribute Value table (EAV table) and is notoriously hard to use and inefficient to query